# Restrict events acces in Odoo calendar

Tags: calendar, odoo, odoo-8

In the Odoo calendar, each user can follow a specific calendar and then see events contained in this calendar.
Is there a way to prevent this functionnality ? The aim is to:

- prevent "classic" user to see all events, he can only add his own events
- admin user has full rights on calendars

I've searched in the configuration but I do not find rules.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-disable-other-user-edit-my-calendar-meeting-2432) is what I came up with from searches today. It didn't help my scenario, but I think this is the way to go for you.

1- Settings >> security >> Record Rule

2- create new record rule on Meeting Object and the domain is

```
['|',('partner_ids','in',user.partner_id.id),('user_id','=',user.id)]
```

For you I think you can remove `('partner_ids','in',user.partner_id.id)`

so it becomes:

['|',('user_id','=',user.id)]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Calendar is open for all.

You have to add the Record rule

Comment: this is not enough, add some more details please

Comment: You can create a group and attach to the Calendar Menu and give access of that group to require users

Comment: please attach the steps to attach to the calendar menu please